# Cannot submit revision of preprint in bioRxiv (Current Version Status Closed)

Tags: preprint, biorxiv

I went to the 'Author Area', and the first sign of problem was that the 'Submit a Revision' link had 0 papers. After that, I went to 'Author history', found the specific preprint. I noticed that the table's column 'Current Version Status' had entry 'Closed'. The preprint has 'Date of Original Submission' on September 2017.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I've searched in bioRxiv's site and in the web, but no clue of any rules related to closing of preprints to revision after some time since last or initial submission.

Answer (score 3):

I contacted the bioRxiv Team. They replied saying that "The system automatically closes submissions if they are inactive over the allotted period of time. We can have this reopened, but first we need confirmation that your paper has not yet been accepted or published in a journal."

I then asked them "How long is the duration of inactivity leading to closing a preprint for revision, since I couldn't find any specification in bioRxiv's website."

They replied that "The timeline for closing a submission that is in progress is two weeks."

Thing is that I couldn't find any mention in their website about closing to revision after a two-week period of inactivity since initial submission; actually, their FAQ says that "An article posted on bioRxiv can be revised at any time, until it is accepted for publication."

Comment: Same problem, and same confusion. But as long as they respond quickly to reopen it, I can't complain!